# How to get chip name for lm-sensors

Tags: ubuntu, temperature, fan

I'm trying to get the current fan speed of our Ubuntu 14.04 Server. The fans are extremely loud so I assume there is something going wrong.

I already installed `lm-sensor`
But it says it needs to know the chip name in order to display

```
$ sensors detect
Parse error in chip name `detect'
Try `sensors -h' for more information
```

However I don't know the chip name and I also don't know how to find it. Can anybody help?
Maybe lm-sensors is too old for our machine since we just bought it.

I guess this is the mainboard name:

```
sysGen/GIGABYTE Barebone SYS-G250-G52
```

Comment: I think that the command you want is: `sensors-detect` .... notice the dash in the name.

Answer (score 3):

If you just start `sensors`, its output will include the chip names if the appropriate kernel modules are loaded:

```
↪ sensors                  
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +29.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +29.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +26.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +26.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +26.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Both `acpitz-virtual-0` and `coretemp-isa-0000` are chip names.

However, I assume you don't want to execute `sensors detect`, but `sensors-detect`, which detects hardware monitoring chips in your system. `sensors detect` instructs `sensors` to print the readings of a chip called `detect`.

Comment: And failing that, the `lshw` utility can show you all the chips, etc.  I'd even use the HTML option adn dump to a file for easy viewing in a browser - `lshw -html > /path/to/html/file`